# Is there any way to pass variables to a validation constraint message in Java?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a requirement where in a validation constraint message I need to include  the String.length() i.e.:

```
@max(value = 50, message = "Max length 50, observed length " + String.length())
```

However I can't do this because it needs to be passed a constant expression. Is there any simple way to deal with this or is it just best to create a separate method checking lengths?

Answer (score 2):

In the end we did it with an EL expression:

```
@max(value = 50, message = "Max length 50, observed length ${String.length()}")
```